# wpf red border around slider control when sliding

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, slider

When sliding my slider control in my WPF app there is a red border that shows up around the outside of the slider.  I want to get rid of it.  This did not happen in .net 3.5.  It just started happening when the app was updated to .net 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a validation border. Do you have validation bindings on your slider?

Comment: didn't have any validation bindings, but was able to do this Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" and its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a validation border. If you don't have any custom validation bindings, it means that some exception occured when you slide.
Open "Debug - Windows - Output" in your debug session. This helped me to resolve a similar issue with my TreeView control.